# Problems with rubber-banding and freezing in CS:GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have started playing CS:GO, but I'm experiencing problems with rubber-banding and players and grenades suddenly freezing. This makes the game unplayable and I really need it fixed. I have played many multiplayer games and never experienced this before, it is exclusive to CS:GO. I have [recorded a video of what is going on](https://youtu.be/Qm90-gVSFwQ) if it helps.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Comment: What kind of server are you playing on (i.e, your own server, a server you found through the "Join Game" menu, etc.)? And what's your ping?

Comment: Have you tried to "Verify Local Cache" via steam? Maybe uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: it looks like internet problems on your side, you could enable `net_graph 1` in your console and look at `ping` whenever you lag around like that and you should see a spike in your ping

Comment: This looks like packet loss from a WiFi connection or something.

Answer (score 2):

The two most likely possibilities are playing with a high ping, or on a low-tick server. If you are on a valve server (64 tick) then you will probably be experiencing ping problems - in which case all I can suggest is you ensure nothing is nibbling on your bandwidth.

as someone who was born into laggy connections I can safely say any background downloads going on around the house can have a VERY severe impact to your connection